# How to disable autocomplete in Firefox using Selenium with Python?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am building an automated test task with Selenium. When I put the first field on a form, the rest of it is autocompleted based on previous attempts. I can clear the fields to handle this, but it would be easier if I could disable autocomplete at all.
Is there a way to do this in Python Selenium?

Edit: I am creating a profile with:

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.accept_untrusted_certs = True
profile.set_preference("security.enable_java", True)
profile.set_preference("plugin.state.java", 2) 
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
```

Comment: Do you start firefox with a custom pre-saved profile?

Comment: @alecxe, I create a new profile. See my edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set [`browser.formfill.enable`](http://kb.mozillazine.org/About:config_entries#Browser.) firefox profile preference to `false` to ask Firefox not to remember and autofill form input values:

```
profile.set_preference("browser.formfill.enable", "false")
```

Comment: There is a mistake in your code. Unfortunately I cannot edit it. "false" vs False without quotes.

Comment: @rfkortekaas as far as I remember, would work either way.

Comment: I wasn't aware of this. Probably this is handled by Firefox itself as there is no conversion or handling for this in selenium. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: This is the right answer, though my problem was occurring because the website was filling the data fields, not the firefox, so this didn't work for my project. I will need to clear the fields anyway

Answer (score 2):

The best option is to create a profile for Firefox which you use with the selenium webdriver:

Start Firefox with the '-p' option to start the profile manager and create a new custom profile.

In the options you can disable the autocomplete:

Go to 'options' > 'privacy' > 'use custom settings for history' and disable 'remember search and form history.

Use the following to use the custom Firefox profile with selenium:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver import FirefoxProfile
profile = FirefoxProfile(path_to_my_profile)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
```

Or you can create a temporary custom profile with selenium itself (omit 'path_to_my_profile') and add the following preference:

```
profile.set_preference('browser.formfill.enable', False)
```

Comment: Is there a way to just add this option when I create the profile, without the need to save a custom profile? I have edited the post with the code I use to create the profile

Comment: Yes, open 'about:config' in Firefox and search for the 'remember search and form history'. Copy the string and use the set_preference as used above.

Comment: @rfkortekaas nothing found matching "remember search and form history" in about:config.

Comment: The correct preference string is 'browser.formfill.enable'