# Python Selenium Autofill issue

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, bots, autofill

I am attempting to make a auto script bot that find a specific item and adds the item to the users cart and so forth. Right now I am getting caught because whenever the code autofills in the user information the phone number and credit card number either come out backwards or mixed up.

[image]

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

# Open chrome web browser and directs to supreme.com

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('http://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/all')

# Find specific item 

browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*
[@id="container"]/article[12]/div/a/img').click()
WebDriverWait(browser,10).until(
EC.visibility_of_any_elements_located((By.ID,'size')))


# Select size 

Select = Select(browser.find_element_by_id('size'))
Select.select_by_visible_text("Large")

# Add to cart

browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="add-remove-buttons"]/input').click()
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="cart"]/a[2]').click()


# Input user info

Name = browser.find_element_by_id('order_billing_name')
Name.send_keys("Justin Malik")

Email = browser.find_element_by_id('order_email')
Email.send_keys("xxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com")

Telephone = browser.find_element_by_id('order_tel')
Telephone.send_keys("3334449875")

Billing_address = browser.find_element_by_id('bo')
Billing_address.send_keys("13002 lala land CT")

Billing_zip = browser.find_element_by_id('order_billing_zip')
Billing_zip.send_keys("33579")

Billing_City = browser.find_element_by_id('order_billing_city')
Billing_City.send_keys()

Billing_State = browser.find_element_by_id('order_billing_state')
Billing_State.send_keys("TX")



# Credit info

Credit_number = browser.find_element_by_id('cnb')
Credit_number.send_keys("1234 5698 7588 4444")

Credit_month = browser.find_element_by_id('credit_card_month')
Credit_month.send_keys("07")

Credit_year = browser.find_element_by_id('credit_card_year')
Credit_year.send_keys("2021")

Credit_verif = browser.find_element_by_id('vval')
Credit_verif.send_keys("334")


# Accept Terms & Agreements 

terms = browser.find_element_by_id('order_terms').click()
```

Comment: Do the phone and CC# fields have auto-formatting on them?  I'm guessing they do and I've hit issues with that in the past where selenium was typing "too fast".

Try making a method that types character by character and has a wait between each one.  Not a long term solution, but can help you debug.

Comment: This didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First delete the fill-up text and then do send keys . Use ActionChain class for that . 
try below example:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

Telephone_field = browser.find_element_by_id('order_tel')

Creditcard_field = browser.find_element_by_id('cnb')

ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(Telephone_field).click().key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys('a').key_up(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys("3334449875").perform()

ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(Creditcard_field).click().key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys('a').key_up(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys("1234 5698 7588 4444").perform()
```

Comment: Hello. One liner or code only answers are not the best way to answer a question. Please add some explanation regarding why you think this would be a good solution.

Comment: I added comment.

Comment: THIS WORKED!.. Can you explain to me why what i had before was giving me the numbers in random order and what is the .keydown and .keyup are for ?

Comment: Keydown will press and hold a key. Here i used it to press and hold  'control ' key then send keys 'a' . It will select existing text of input. Then key up will release 'Control'  key. Then send keys will overwrite it with given text.

Answer (score 0):

Which browser are you using? You might be able to disable auto-fill like this:

```
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("--disable-single-click-autofill");
    options.addArguments("--disable-autofill-keyboard-accessory-view[8]");
    driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Or perhaps trying setting your own profile and try to delete the cookies before you start your test!
The above was taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38273718/how-to-disable-autocomplete-in-firefox-using-selenium-with-python).

If the above are not sufficient, you can perhaps allow autofill to work once and then go and delete quickly all the auto-fill entries. So call a cleanup before you type:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="elementWhichWasAutoFilled"]/input').clear()
```

Comment: I am currently in class but this might work cause I notice it auto fills my city and keep wondering how it does that even though I left that blank in the code

Comment: I am using chrome @Xwris Stoixeia

Comment: Ok updated the answer, have your tried deleting [element.clear()] before typing by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set value of each input field with `JavaScript`:

```
Telephone = browser.find_element_by_id('order_tel')
Credit_number = browser.find_element_by_id('cnb')
browser.execute_script('arguments[0].value="3334449875";', Telephon)
browser.execute_script('arguments[0].value="1234569875884444";', Credit_number)
```

Comment: I notice the cc and phone number text fields have (___) ___-____ already in the text box. You can place a number anywhere on those lines , how would python now to start left to right in this situation because it does the street address as well as the zip code just fine