# How to disable autocomplete to send text to username field with selenium chrome python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, autocomplete, css-selectors

This is my python/selenium code

```
username = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="username"]')
password = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="password"]')
enter = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="loginbox"]/input[3]')

passfile = open(alltools.get_letter() + "path\pass.txt", "r")
line = passfile.readlines()

username.send_keys(line[0])
password.send_keys(line[1])
enter.click()
```

The form I'm trying to fill is

```
<form style="align: center;" id="loginForm" method="post" action="j_security_check" autocomplete="off">
      <div class="identity-box" id="loginbox">
        <div class="alert-error" style="display: none">Invalid username or password</div>
        <label class="label" for="username">Username</label>
        <input type="text" class="text-input" size="30" name="j_username" id="username">
        <label class="label" for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="text-input" size="30" name="j_password" id="password">
        <input type="submit" class="button" value="Sign In">
      </div>
    </form>
```

I know the issue is with the `autocomplete="off"`. How do I turn it off?

Comment: what driver do you use? Chrome or Firefox?

Comment: for firefox you can try something like this. disable autocomplete for browser https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38273718/how-to-disable-autocomplete-in-firefox-using-selenium-with-python

Comment: It's chrome driver

Answer (score 0):

### autocomplete Attribute

Generally [autocomplete](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_autocomplete_off.asp) attribute is used to turn off autocomplete for input fields. As an example:

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off">
```

[autocomplete](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_autocomplete.asp) can also be turned off autocomplete for the whole form:

```
<form autocomplete="off">
```

---

### This usecase

As per the HTML you have shared [autocomplete](/questions/tagged/autocomplete) is turned off at the `<form>` level:

```
<form style="align: center;" id="loginForm" method="post" action="j_security_check" autocomplete="off">
```

You should be good to go.

To send a *character sequence* to the **Username** field you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("label[for='username']").send_keys("thepepp")
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[@for='username']").send_keys("thepepp")
  ```

---

Ideally, to send a *character sequence* to the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "label[for='username']"))).send_keys("thepepp")
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//label[@for='username']"))).send_keys("thepepp")
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: and yet it does not work, it might be the action="j_security_check" as it shows up in the link after python attempts to populate the form.

Comment: @thepepp Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.